# "conda: command not found", Bash on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, shell, anaconda, conda

I have installed Bash for windows by activating the Windows Subsystem for Linux and installing Ubuntu and when I installed Anaconda I selected the "Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable" setting, so I do not believe there are any issues with PATH.
What I see in my Edit environment variables window is:

```
C:\Users\user\anaconda3
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Scripts\
```

In Bash, when I enter something such as `conda info --base` I get `conda: command not found`
However, when I run the same command in Git Bash, it runs just fine.

Comment: The Windows PATH variable and the Linux Subsystem PATH variable are two different things :-)

Comment: @Dominique while that would usually be the case, with Windows' tight integration, the PATH from the host is merged into the subsystem. i am not able to find _where_ this is happening, but it is most certainly happening

Comment: @Dominique refer [this dev blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/more-easily-invoke-windows-apps-and-tools-from-bash-on-windows/#:~:text=Windows%20user%20environment%20path%20is%20now%20appended%20to%20the%20WSL%20path%20by%20default.) from Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

From within git bash, you can type, `command -v conda`, as it will output the location to the executable. Add the directory to your `PATH` environment variable.

Eg from within git bash:

```
$ command -v my_command
/c/path/to/bin/my_command
```

Then prefix the value with `/mnt` and add it all: `/mnt/c/path/to/bin` to your PATH environment variable. And reopen your bash shell.

Comment: git-bash paths ≠ WSL paths. `C:\` in git-bash is `/c`; in WSL is `/mnt/c`

Comment: @kevinnls than change it accordingly?

Comment: i was simply explaining the reason for my downvote. albeit poorly formatted: `C:` in git-bash is `/c/` ; in WSL is `/mnt/c` :) feel free to change your answer accordingly

Comment: There we go....

Answer (score 1):

you can:

1. use git-bash / PowerShell / CMD for Anaconda

   - use [Windows Terminal](//aka.ms/terminal) for easily using multiple shells
2. modify `~/.profile` to include the Anaconda folders to `PATH`. `/mnt/c/Users/user/Anaconda3...`

   - **NB** you *may* experience issues with file paths or output
   - in advance, you could check the output of `echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}" | grep -i conda` in a **new** session of `bash`

     - because typically, Windows and WSL should have already [configured this for you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/more-easily-invoke-windows-apps-and-tools-from-bash-on-windows/#:%7E:text=Windows%20user%20environment%20path%20is%20now%20appended%20to%20the%20WSL%20path%20by%20default.)
3. install Anaconda on WSL following [official Linux instructions for your distro](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux.html)

   - if unsure which distro, it's likely Ubuntu. so instructions for Debian, the parent of Ubuntu

WSL is a complete Linux virtual machine and not your best bet for running (cli) software that you installed on Windows. you *can* but i would personally prefer installing the Linux version in WSL.

Comment: `echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"` will only list all directories in the PATH environment variable, making the pipe to grep only match anything if the directory contains `conda`.

Comment: @Andreas Louv that is the intent

Comment: ... If the directory name contains `conda`.

Comment: ... which is a _part_ of anaconda3... which is the name of OP's installation directory... `C:\Users\user\anaCONDA3`